# Windbg - dumping System.Guid

Tags: windbg, sos

When I use !do in windbg for System.Guid object I got list of fields for that GUID object. How can I see what is value of this GUID (string representation)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `dt nt!_GUID  <@ofobject> +4`

Comment: Actually, I am testing on 64bit machine so in my case  dt nt!_GUID <@ofobject> +8 is OK. Thanks.

Comment: For me when I do managed debugging and get the address via SOS, the correct value is shown when I do dt nt!_GUID <@ofobject>

Comment: If this object is a value type. Use dt nt!_guid <@ofobject>

Answer (score 0):

Guid is stored as ints and bytes. String representation is created when you call ToString(). You can not call methods if you analyzing a 'dead' dump file. So your best bet is to just copy the values and use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx22893a.aspx) and ToString() in a new console app or in a unit test:

```
public Guid(
    uint a,
    ushort b,
    ushort c,
    byte d,
    byte e,
    byte f,
    byte g,
    byte h,
    byte i,
    byte j,
    byte k
)
```

Not the answer you were looking for probably. Hope you only need to do it once.

Comment: Unfortunately... If you need to check dozen of GUIDs it will be painful.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Using WinDbg frequently may indicate that you missing unit tests and that design needs to be improved. The answer I provided is good for 'once in a while' session with windbg. Good luck.